# How is "transfer speed" relevant to a 4k KVM switch?

Tags: kvm-switch, 4k-resolution, refresh-rate, transfer-rate

I'm researching KVM switches to hook my USB keyboard and USB mouse to a Dell laptop running Windows 10 and an Ubuntu 19.10 Linux desktop, so that both can drive a 4k monitor using HDMI cables.

My use-case is for crisp-text-display, not gaming. Thus, a 60Hz refresh rate is seen as a "must-have".

Researching led me to [The 9 Best HDMI Switchers of 2020](https://www.lifewire.com/best-hdmi-switchers-4134646) which has a [Zettaguard Upgraded 4K 60Hz 4x1 HDMI Switcher Review](http://Zettaguard%20Upgraded%204K%2060Hz%204x1%20HDMI%20Switcher%20Review) which states:

> Thanks to its 18Gbps transfer speed, it worked reliably with our PS4, Nintendo Switch, and PC with no noticeable latency.

Compare that statement with https://superuser.com/a/1469656/106977 which said:

> There is no added latency or loss of quality

Thus, I'm confused by the reviewers reference to "transfer speed". What data is being transferred here that is relevant to my use-case?  Is it referring to the latency when I switch between the two HDMI inputs from the two machines, or relevant to the refresh rate? Or is it a sales gimmick?

## Update 1

Later on in my research, I stumbled upon a video for a competing brand of KVM switch back in Dec 7 2018, at https://youtu.be/HgZgIWFysL8?t=123 (link goes to 123s into the video) where it claims:

> Each unit comes with its own remote control, power supply, and two high quality KVM cables. These KVM cables are capable of transmitting 18 gigabits per second, which allows the full Ultra HD experience with a 4k capable monitor. For ease of use, the cables have both an HDMI, and USB end, but can be used independently of each other.

Furthering my confusion and suspicion about this being a sales gimmick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What data is being transferred here that is relevant to my use-case?

Your image data. 4K at 60 Hz needs between 10 and 18 Gb/s depending on color resolution.

So if you want a "crisp image" (which probably means enough color resolution), go for a switch that supports 18 Gb/s, and make sure to buy the right HDMI cables that support that speed.

> Is it referring to the latency when I switch between the two HDMI inputs from the two machines, or relevant to the refresh rate?

The answer refers to a potential latency in transmission.

There is a whole different kind of pause (I wouldn't call that "latency") during switching, which mostly comes from the computer now having to recognize that a HDMI device is active, and bringing up the HDMI output. Which is a few seconds on my systems.

> Or is it a sales gimmick?

It's no sales gimmick; a KVM or HDMI cable only supporting a lower speed may force you to use less color resolution and/or a lower refresh rate and/or a lower resolution.